# iOS - iFrame meta viewport issue

Tags: ios, google-chrome, iframe, viewport, meta

I have ran into an iOS **ONLY** specific bug which i cannot seem to wrap my head around. I am currently rendering an iframe on a website which is fetching content from another one of my websites. The content in the iframe is displayed within a responsive slider. The slider works by getting the full width of the window and times that by how many slides there is.

To make it responsive it will recalculate the widths on `jQuery(window).resize`. At this point i would like to add that i have tested this on all browsers on pc and its fine, ive tried it on all android browsers and guess what, they all work fine. As soon as i take it to IOS for testing is where the problem begins.

It works fine if you visit the dedicated website. However, When you view the content through the iframe, the javascript code thinks that the window is being resized which means its constantly resizing (getting bigger and bigger) making it dissapear of the screen making the window continually wider everytime.

HTML

```
<div class="iframe-container">
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="*url removed*"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.iframe-container iframe{width: 100%; min-height: 560px; border: none;}
```

Im thinking that its possible related to the content within the iframe ignoring the meta viewport tag or something?

Im unable to post a link to the issue due to client privacy reasons.

If anyone could shed some light on this, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Lewis

Answer (score 0):

In case it's still relevant or for anyone brought here by search:

Find the element *inside* the iframe which makes the window get bigger and bigger. Add `max-width: 100vw;` to its styles.

This helped me to fix a similar issue which also occurred *only* on ios and *only* when the page was loaded in an iframe.